# Include resize img in this jQuery

Tags: magento-1.9, image, product-view, jquery

My "more view" images are being called by the following jQuery but it's leaving the thumb images huge at their original size. How can I resize them proportionally to 100px?

```
    var imagefile='<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media');?>catalog/product'+file;
        jQuery("#ul-moreviews").prepend('<li>
<a class="thumb" title="'+label+'" onClick="$('+'image'+').src =this.href; changeLabel(this); return false;"     href="'+imagefile+'"><img title="'+label+'"src="'+imagefile+'"></a>
    <div class="caption-more"><h6>'+display_label+'</h6></div></li>');
                                    });
```

Comment: how to get  file value?

Answer (score 2):

you need  `resize image to php variable,it not good idea to resize directly using jquery`.

```
foreach (Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($PrdoductId)->getMediaGalleryImages() 
as $_image): 

        $smallImage = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_image, 'image')->resize(100)->setQuality(100);  
        endforeach;
```

**code may like:**

```
<?php
foreach (Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($PrdoductId())->getMediaGalleryImages() as $_image): 
$smallImage = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_image, 'image')->resize(100)->setQuality(100);  
?>

 var imagefile='<?php echo $smallImage;?>';
        jQuery("#ul-moreviews").prepend('<li>
<a class="thumb" title="'+label+'" onClick="$('+'image'+').src =this.href; changeLabel(this); return false;"     href="'+imagefile+'"><img title="'+label+'"src="'+imagefile+'"></a>
    <div class="caption-more"><h6>'+display_label+'</h6></div></li>');
                                    });  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**magento product image resize**

below code:

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_imageObject, 'image')->resize(100)->setQuality(100);
```

**Using resize(width,height) function image**

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(301); ?>
```